# Select all cells in a row

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

How can I select all cells in a row in Excel / Google Spreadsheet?

I know I can select all cells in a column using

```
A:A
```

But how can I select all cells in a row?

This doesn't work:

```
1:1 // select all cells in first row
```

Comment: 1:1 is the correct format. 
Are you able to provide an example of the formula you're trying to get running?

Answer (score 5):

Simply click on the row's tag (the grey row headers on the left)

[image]

Comment: Just had to up vote this because it directly answer the question :)